# SQLite - select 3 conditions from table and GROPING BY

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this table after joins:

```
   p_id  |a_name |bY  |   city   |   a_id  |p_id|  role   |t_name|p_id|
304804123|Shir   |1980|beer sheba|304804123|111 |meri     |Abima |111 |
304226152|Noa    |1992|tel aviv  |304226152|111 |sonia    |Abima |111 |
251445841|Avi    |1998|haifa     |251445841|222 |tov tov  |Miskan|222 |
204458952|Dani   |1993|sderot    |204458952|222 |gamad    |Abima |222 |
221354875|Osher  |1995|beer sheba|221354875|333 |prince   |Akamri|333 |
304804123|Shir   |1980|beer sheba|304804123|222 |princes  |Abima |222 |
304804123|Shir   |1980|beer sheba|304804123|333 |singar   |Abima |333 |
304226152|Noa    |1992|tel aviv  |304226152|333 |singarit |Abima |333 |
304226152|Noa    |1992|tel avia  |304226152|333 |singarit2|Abima |333 |
```

what I need from the table is all the actors names (a_name) who played at least three plays (p_id) and whose birth year(bY) is 1980 or more.
i can get it according to the next query:

```
SELECT a_name FROM (SELECT *, COUNT(Play.p_id) AS 
    COUNT_NUM_OF_PLAY_EACH_ACTOR 
FROM Actor, Play, Role WHERE 
    Actor.a_id = Role.a_id AND Role.p_id = Play.p_id
GROUP BY a_name) WHERE COUNT_NUM_OF_PLAY_EACH_ACTOR >= 3 
    AND birthYear >= 1980;
```

result:

```
Noa
Shir
```

but added to my condition that if a player appeared in more than one role in the same show it is still considered one show.
In me query the actor Noa played in 111, 444, 333 show, but she played 2 roles in 333 show, how can I treat it as one show?

desired outcome:

```
Noa <- remove this because noa played in 2 shows only and not 3.
Shir
```

Comment: You need to use `COUNT(DISTINCT Play.p_id)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use distinct for the same please try below one

```
SELECT a_name FROM (SELECT *, COUNT(distinct Play.p_id) AS 
    COUNT_NUM_OF_PLAY_EACH_ACTOR 
FROM Actor, Play, Role WHERE 
    Actor.a_id = Role.a_id AND Role.p_id = Play.p_id
GROUP BY a_name) WHERE COUNT_NUM_OF_PLAY_EACH_ACTOR >= 3 
    AND birthYear >= 1980;
```

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  In addition, you do not need a subquery:

```
SELECT a.a_id, a.name  -- in case two actors have the same name
FROM Actor a JOIN
     Role r
     ON a.a_id = r.a_id
WHERE a.birth_year >= 1980
GROUP BY a.a_id, a.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT r.p_id) >= 3;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- You should include `a_id` in the `GROUP BY`, to handle the situation where two actors have the same name.
- The subquery is not necessary.
- Use `JOIN` !!!